# Point to Struct in Golang

Tags: pointers, go

I has encountered an error while implement the below code:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt" 
)

type Struct struct {
    a int
    b int
}

func Modifier(ptr *Struct, ptrInt *int) int {
    *ptr.a++
    *ptr.b++
    *ptrInt++
    return *ptr.a + *ptr.b + *ptrInt
}

func main() { 
    structure := new(Struct)
    i := 0         
    fmt.Println(Modifier(structure, &i))
}
```

That gives me an error something about "invalid indirect of ptr.a (type int)...". And also why the compiler don't give me error about ptrInt? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Just do

```
func Modifier(ptr *Struct, ptrInt *int) int {
    ptr.a++
    ptr.b++
    *ptrInt++
    return ptr.a + ptr.b + *ptrInt
}
```

You were in fact trying to apply `++` on `*(ptr.a)` and `ptr.a` is an int, not a pointer to an int.

You could have used `(*ptr).a++` but this is not needed as Go automatically solves `ptr.a` if `ptr` is a pointer, that's why you don't have `->` in Go.

Comment: Thanks for the answer, that's helpful for me.